# In eclipse, how to import java lib under nested folders not one by one with jar?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse version: Juno Release

I want to import lots of libs not one by one with jar, but import them with folder.

My lib structure is as follow.

```
/whatever/lib
 folder_1
     xxx.jar
     xxx_0.jar
     ...
 folder_2
     folder_2_0
         xxx_1.jar
         xxx_2.jar
         ...
 folder_3
     folder_3_0
         folder3_0_0
             xxx_3.jar
             ...
 ...
 xxx_3.jar
 xxx_4.jar
 ...
```

How to import them with path `/whatever/lib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own user library and add that to your project. (User library is a folder consists of jar files). To add a library you have to go to build path (Select project, right-click -> configure build path) of project and add it.:

Create a folder and put jar files in that folder. Follow below screenshot and select that folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom libraries and add them to your projects. More specifically you could create a **User Library** for a folder and add jars inside the library and finally add that library to your Java Build Path.